# The set $A'$ is closed in a $T_1$ space

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a $T_1$ space, and $A\subset E$ , I need to prove that $A'$ is closed, so my idea is to prove that $C_{E}A'$ is open i.e a neighborhood of all it's point.

But how to do this ?

Comment: What is $A'{}$?

Comment: Prehaps it might be helpful to readers to explain the notation you are using. In particular what is $A'$ and what is $C_E A'$?

Comment: @Eric: $A'$ is the set of limit points of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If $x\in E\setminus A'$, then $x$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ such that $U_x\cap A$ contains at most one point. Show that $U_x\cap A'=\varnothing$.

Comment: I dont understand, we have by definition that $x\in C_{E}A'$ means that there exists $V\in \mathcal{V}_x$ such that $V\setminus\{x\}\cap A =\emptyset$ why we must show that $U_x\cap A'=\emptyset$

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Your $V$ is my $U_x$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary point of $E\setminus A'$, if you show that its intersection with $A'$ is empty, you’ve shown that $E\setminus A'$ is open.

Comment: i dont understand the idea why the intersection with $A'$ why not  with $A$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Because you’re trying to prove that the complement of $A'$ is open. To do that, you need to show that each point of that complement has a nbhd contained in the complement – which means a nbhd disjoint from $A'$, *not* a nbhd disjoint from $A$.

Comment: Ok i understand but i have no idea how to do to prove this

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Suppose that $y\in U_x$. If $U_x\cap A=\varnothing$, then $U_x$ is a nbhd of $y$ disjoint from $A$, which shows that $y\notin A'$. If $U_x\cap A\ne\varnothing$, then $x\in A$, and $U_x\cap A=\{x\}$. Now use the fact that $E$ is $T_1$ to find an open nbhd of $y$ disjoint from $A$, thereby showing that $y\notin A'$.

Comment: We have that $U_{x}\setminus \{x\}\cap A=\emptyset$ i dont understant how you started your proof

Comment: @Vrouvrou: I don’t understand what it is that you don’t understand. Either $U_x\cap A=\{x\}$, which is the case if $x\in A$, or $U_x\cap A=\varnothing$, which is the case if $x\notin A$. I started by considering the second of these cases and left the first to you.

Comment: You choose $U_x$ open ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: I did indeed: check the wording of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30360/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-brian-m-scott).